# why I can't open a flyout with a ImageButton on windows - .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, flyout

I have added an ImageButton in my MAUI application to open the flyout. The command that calls the button works and is well executed but the following line of code (which is to open the flyout, [link to flyout documentation on microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout)) only works on Android but not on Windows (I have not tested on macOS and IOS).

```
private void ShowFlyoutExecute(object obj)
{
     Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;
}
```

Do you have a solution to this problem or is it normal and if so what alternative do I have?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem with visual studio `17.2.0` preview .

However, the issue has been resolved after I updated visual studio to `17.3.0`(preview 1.0).

So you can try to update visual studio to see if the problem persists.

See the issue here : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5932#issuecomment-1120167743 .

Comment: Unfortunately FlyoutIsPresented still not working properly on 17.4.0. The FlyoutIsPresented is set to 'true' to begin with, when the flyout is not visible. Sporadically working if page is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

I'm running VS 17.3.2. `FlyoutIsPresented = true;` does not work in my Android emulator. It works just fine when running in Windows.